# Register/Login using a MD5 hash Password JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, md5, password-hash

I'm trying to create a login/register system that uses MD5 hashed passwords.

So far I've managed to hash the passwords in the database however it doesn't recognise the hashed passwords when trying to login.

Probably a simple fix, any help will do :)

REGISTER JAVA

```
String s8 = tfPassword.getText();

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                        md.update(s8.getBytes());
                        byte [] byteData = md.digest();

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
                        for (byte b : byteData) {
                            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                        }

Statement st = con.createStatement();

st.executeUpdate("insert into Login (StaffID, UName, PWord, Staff) values('"+StaffID+"','"+s7+"','"+sb+"','Yes')");
```

LOGIN JAVA:

```
String s2 = tfPassword.getText();

                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    md.update(s2.getBytes());
                    byte [] byteData = md.digest();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
                    for (byte b : byteData) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                    }

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();   


                    // SQL Statements 
                    st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login WHERE UName= '"+s1+"' and PWord = '"+sb+"'");
```

Comment: As an aside, this code is rife with [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) potential

Comment: "that uses MD5 hashed passwords" MD5 is not a cryptographically secure hash. You can crack every 7 character password in less than an hour on a standard GPU.

Comment: Thank you guys for your advice however, how do i go about comparing the hashed passwords?

Comment: Cool story. So here's some code that doesn't work. *Was* there a *question*? StackOverflow is *not* a debugging service https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future SOuls that find this question in their search for answer about "MD5 hash password" :

Using MD5 hash for passwords is *broken*. Don't do it.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

While we're on the topic of security, we are also going to encourage the use of prepared statements with bind placeholders, rather than writing dynamic SQL that  is (or appears to be) vulnerable to SQL Injection.

---

Looks like the question wasn't about MD5 for passwords at all. It looks like it is really a much simpler question:

**Q: How do I tell if an executed SELECT statement returned a(ny) row(s)?**

**A:** The `executeQuery` method returns a `ResultSet` object if the statement if the SQL statement is a `SELECT`. Use the `next` method to retrieve the next row from the resultset.

Something like this:

```
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

      st = con.CreateStatement();
      rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT '42' AS fortytwo");

      while( rs.next() ) {
        String foo = rs.getString("fortytwo");
        // System.out.println("yay! we got another row!");
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      //
    } finally {
       if (rs != null) { rs.close(); }
       ...
```